# How to render related nodes by vocabulary X on vocabulary Y terms?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I did many research about related nodes by term. These solutions are good with related nodes by term on node pages but does not work on term pages.

Solutions I found: Add "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" in Views - Contextual filters.

- [Related nodes by taxonomy term in a view block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64834/related-nodes-by-taxonomy-term-in-a-view-block)
- [How do I show related content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205921/how-do-i-show-related-content)
- [Views Related Content module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_related_content)

My idea:

- Content type A node with term reference X
- Vocabulary Y terms with term reference X
- render content type A node with related term reference X on Vocabulary Y terms

Comment: Instead of saying "type A node", "vocabulary Y", and "term reference X", can you put the names of the node types, vocabularies, and terms? Also, could you please give a real-world example of the scenario, and what you want the result to be? Something like `If a node has a taxonomy reference field for the vocabulary "colors", and it has a value of "blue" then the view should show all nodes with the terms "teal", "indigo" and "azure"`. Be sure to include how the terms relate to each other, like `Vocabulary "colors" has the term "blue", with the child terms "teal", "indigo" and "azure"`.

Comment: Oh, it would also be helpful if you say what the view shouldn't show. For example `The term "indigo" has the child term "indigo (crayola)", and nodes with the term "indigo (crayola)" should not be included in the view`.